# PWM with 555 timer IC

Tags: pwm, 555

I am trying to build a PWM signal with 555 timer. I am following [this](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/555-timer-astable-circuit/) website to build my circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo939n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have placed my components in my breadboard as shown in the schematic I have placed above. I am trying to observe the intensity of my LED at different duty cycles. But I am not being able to find the correct resistor value for R1 to get the duty cycle of 25%.

Some maths I have done:

I fixed the value of R2 to be 330 Ohms. I have my capacitor rated 1 microfarads.

If T(on) is the on time of LED then: T(on)=0.693*C*(R1+R2).

If T(off) is the off time of LED then: T(off)=0.693*C*R2.

So, total time period of the signal = T(total)=0.693*C*(R1+2R2).

The duty cycle is now T(on)/T(total)=(R1+R2)/(R1+2R2).

Starting from the lower duty cycle, I wanted 25% duty cycle first. The calculation gives me the value of R1 to be negative. Note that I have the R2 value to be 330ohms.

What's the thing that I am missing?

Comment: With your configuration you cannot have a duty cycle of under 50%. This is because  the circuit has two time constants, t1, t2. t1 is charging up, and is (R1+R2)*C. t2 is discharge, and is R2*C. The charging up time will always be longer than the discharging time, meaning the duty cycle can only approach 50% at lowest as R1 goes to 0Ω (don't let R1 go to 0Ω).

Comment: This is a canned comment to let you know that it looks like you're trying to implement something that is non-trivial with the power-hungry NE555 but is very easy for someone using a microcontroller.

Comment: Try connecting your LED between the output and Vcc instead of GND, and configure your 555 for 75% duty- cycle.

Comment: @brhans. I will try that for sure.

Comment: Depending on how accurate you need it, you can also "tune" the PWM by putting a potentiometer across pin 5 to ground.